# Sublist inside simple list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a doubt to confirm. Let there is a list

```
  f = {{l}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}
```

And I expect it to be traversed as a normal list which I can do by,

```
Table[f[[i, k]], {i, Length[f]}, {k, Length[f[[i]]]}]
```

But if the list is

```
a = {b, c, d, e, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}
```

Than I get the following output

```
   {{}, {}, {}, {}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}}
```

Is it must that there shall be list of sublists and no single element can be kept without sublist or I am accessing it wrong way. Doesn't Mathematica automatically consider it to be sublist for obvious reason.

Comment: ...and you've just seen that `Part[]` does not do anything too useful to symbols, as opposed to what it does for lists and list-like objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple form:

```
f = {a, b};
f[[1]]
```

gives you

```
a
```

as you expect. But what is the length of f[[1]]?

```
Length[f[[1]]]
0
```

Which explains why your `Table` operates the way it does: the length of any symbol is 0. In fact, the length of any indivisible object (like a number or a symbol or a string) is 0, as is the length of any expression for which `AtomQ` is True.